# Google sign not working on API lower than Nougat

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-6.0-marshmallow, google-signin, google-api-client

I tried following the snippets on Google sign in but instead of putting it on an activity, I use it on a fragment. It only works on nougat. The problem seems to rely on the intent being given to Google. It closes my app whenever I click the sign in Google.

The dialog shows up outside my app and it does not comeback to my fragment. It just closes down.

So here's my code: it's almost the same as the snippet. but the problem here is that when the app closes down when I click sign in Google, it lets the user pick the email everytime, but it does not go back to the onActivityResult as there is no logged data on my logcat

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment implements OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    private Button signUp, login;
    private View view;
    private SharedPref pref;


    private SignInButton signInButton;
    private GoogleSignInOptions gso;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    private static final String TAG = "GPlusFragment";

    private Retrofit retrofit;
    private RequestInterface requestInterface;
    private ServerRequest request;
    private boolean connectionError = false;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .requestProfile()
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .enableAutoManage(getActivity() /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_layout, container, false);
        signUp = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.signup);
        login = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.login);
        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();


        //Initializing signinbutton
        signInButton = (SignInButton) view.findViewById(R.id.google_sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        mGoogleApiClient.stopAutoManage(getActivity());
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        connectionError = true;
        signInButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        //mGoogleApiClient.stopAutoManage(getActivity());
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        if (connectionError){
            mGoogleApiClient.stopAutoManage(getActivity());
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            signInButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        signUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack("signup").replace(R.id.content_view, new RegisterFragment());
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack("signin").replace(R.id.content_view, new SignInFragment());
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });

        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
                Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d("It's here", "here");
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
                GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
                handleSignInResult(result);
            }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
             //my code here doing the login
          }
    }

    public void goToProfile(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), HomeLoggedInActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem has been resolved by removing the 
            android:noHistory="true" in the manifest. It was a solution before for preventing users from going back to the login activity.

Comment: If your issue has been resolved please mark this as the answer

Comment: I'll do it after two days.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your actual android phone instead of the emulator since it has an old version of google play

Comment: Nah, some people tested it and told that google sign in do not do anything.

If you want to check the app itself: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.infoman.ibenta